# solr-master slave using MIG and load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, solr, high-availability, solrcloud, solr4

i am setting up solr master slave setup in gcp using servers and for HA using MIG and load balancer.
setup is done but master is not picking up slave. weird thing is both servers are communicating and all firewalls are in place.

in slave solrconfig.xml file, the host ip is mentioned as load balancer ip
and load balancer is internal load balancer and instance group is managed instance group

any help here is highly appreciated

any specific changes to be made??